# Is ditto strategically good for battles?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Ditto takes the stats and moves of the pokemon it transforms into, so it can "be" anything. Does this make ditto a good choice in a multiplayer battle? If so, what are some good strategies with ditto?

I'm specifically interested in Ditto's strategy for Pokémon X/Y.

Comment: Can you add a little more to your question to make this more objective? It's quite broad as it stands.

Comment: Please clarify which generation you're referring to, as Ditto's mechanics have changed over the years.

Comment: @Yuki: Looking over the edits, qwertyk31 added a Pokémon XY gen (before someone else changed it to say 6th gen), so s/he took your advice.

Comment: @Kevin I changed it to sixth-gen. The [community consensus](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7779/pokemon-x-and-y-tag-canonicalization/) is to tag mechanics questions with [pokemon-sixth-gen], and game-specific things (like locations of NPCs/story sequences etc) with [pokemon-xy].

Comment: @Robotnik why aren't the tags merged as one?

Comment: @qwertyk31 - The community wants to future-proof the tags - i.e. when Nintendo eventually releases Pokemon Z or Pokemon Ruby 2/ Saphire 2, most of the mechanics questions will relate to **all** of those games. having a generation tag helps stop duplicate questions for every game. (Would your question about ditto be any different if it were about pokemon Z?)

Comment: @Robotnik: I just wanted to point out that qwertk31 did edit the post him/herself in response to Yuki. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ditto excels at one thing in particular: scouting. Ditto allows its user to know exactly what moveset an opponent has without having to do any guesswork. This can be extremely valuable because several Pokemon can run multiple varied move sets and different roles. Determining a moveset is crucial to discovering what role a Pokemon plays in its team, and therefore how to defeat said team.

Ditto also does marginally well in countering sweepers by using their own stats and movesets against them. Dragon-types are particularly susceptible because they are weak to their own STAB attacks. If Ditto can get the jump on a Dragon-type sweeper, it can often take it out in short order even if you take boosting moves into account as Ditto copies stat boosts as well.

The problem with Ditto is that it spends one turn as itself because it needs to use Transform to adopt another Pokemon's stats. This means that any Pokemon that can outspeed it (which is several) can hit it with a super-effective Fighting move before it can Transform and possibly faint it before it gets started.

To use Ditto in competitive battles, you need support. This can come in the form of Wish, which can heal it in case it survives the initial hit; Reflect, which halves all physical damage; Light Screen, which halves all special damage; or any combination of the above or more.

Barring any support, leading with Ditto almost inevitably requires that you have its Hidden Ability, Imposter. Imposter allows Ditto to Transform as soon as it's sent out, without having to wait for you to spend a turn. This is crucial if you want to run Ditto as a lead or without support because that one turn is absolutely vital.

Also, note that while Ditto will copy stats including temporary stat boosts, Ditto will *not* copy base HP nor will it copy HP EVs. So, you will want to put at least 252 HP EVs if you're fielding a Ditto.

Comment: This explains very well how one can make use of Ditto, but it doesn't exactly explain why someone would want to use it in the first place.

Comment: how do you get imposter?

Comment: @qwertyk31 It is a hidden ability, meaning it can only be found on a Ditto caught in the Friend Safari.

Comment: @Nolonar Added info on Ditto's role.

Comment: @dlras2 I could have sworn I captured a Ditto with the imposter ability in the Pokemon Village.

Comment: @C-dizzle pokemon that show up as part of a horde can sometimes have hidden abilities. That being said I do not know if ditto will horde.

Comment: @UnderscoreZero Ditto does not horde, the only way to get his Hidden Ability is through Friend Safari.

Comment: OMG! The horrors of a ditto horde, if it existed!!!